# Does any one how to execute this cmd through shell script?

Tags: macos, shell

Does any one know how to execute below cmd through shell script?

```
#!/bin/sh

USERNAME="XYZ"

defaultCmd=`defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions "{ \"USERNAME\" = \"${USERNAME}\" ;}" `
```

where `write com.apple.Xcode` is a .plist file. The above command works perfectly on terminal.

Comment: What error messages do you get running from a script? Try escaping the the '(,)' chars with '\( ... \)'. Good luck. Posgt your actual shell script or put set -vx to debug just before the line you are intersted in and set +vx after it.

Comment: @shelter: Updated original post - it's only write a single constant in the above file. Don't get any error/exception after executing the script through terminal but the constant values are not written in the **com.apple.Xcode** file.

Comment: I didn't have my glasses on earlier. So it is { } chars. I don't think there is a need to escape them. Sorry about that distraction. Why are you capturing the output to the variable defaultCmd? If you want to execute 'defaults write', eliminate defaultCmd=\` and the closing \` in your scriptFile and see if that works. Which shell? Bash or ksh or ?

Comment: It's bash shell and according to your suggestion it give me the below exception:

`defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions "{ \"USERNAME\" = \"${USERNAME}\" ;}": command not found`

Comment: in your command window, do `which defaults`, the use the full path for that command, i.e. '/var/macOS/bin/defaults' in your script. (/var/... is just an example, use the full path generated from which ... Good luck!

Comment: It's still not working :( by doing both ways with or without ' special character `/usr/bin/defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions "{ \"USERNAME\" = \"${USERNAME}\" ;}"`

Comment: same error msg, Cmd not found? or plist file not changing? Maybe you need to add a MacOS tag to this question. (I'm not a Mac expert). Gotta go, back in 1 hr.

Comment: No error msg. plist file is not update with the value...Thnx for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@shelter was right - the above command run without '...' and should not be captured any value in the script. But one thing need to be noted that script should not run as "root" user otherwise this command would have no effect.

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions "{ \"USERNAME\" = \"${USERNAME}\" ;}"
```